# How to check if string contain space after each letter

Tags: php, regex

Am trying to check if string has space after each letter, I tried writing below code but it didn't work fine, any idea how I can archive this.

```
public static function hasWhitespace($text){
    $array = str_split($text);
    $i = 0;
    $check = array();
    foreach($array as $w){
        if ($i % 2 == 1){
            $check[] = empty($w);
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return (array_filter($check) == $check);
}
```

Usage and Expected output

```
hasWhitespace("A") true
hasWhitespace("A 3 B") true
hasWhitespace("V 3 A 3 B") true
hasWhitespace("G B A 3 B 9 V") true

hasWhitespace("A3") false 
hasWhitespace("A3 B H 6") false
hasWhitespace("A3B") false
```

Comment: `return preg_match('~^(\w( |$))+$~', $text);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex in `preg_match` to validate your input:

```sh
^[\pL\d](?:\h[\pL\d])*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yLwSWp/2)

**Code:**

```sh
$re = '/^[\pL\d](?:\h+[\pL\d])*$/';
if (preg_match($re, $str))
   echo "valid";
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `[\pL\d]`: Match a letter or digit
- `(?:\h[\pL\d])*`: Match 0 or more single space separated letters or digits
- `$`: End

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems in your code, is that you check for a space using `empty()`, which a space isn't empty.

This code uses a loop, but loops over every other character (starting from 1 - the second char) and checks it, if it's not a space then it returns false...

```
function hasWhitespace($text){
    for ( $i = 1; $i < strlen($text); $i += 2)  {
        if ( $text[$i] != ' ' ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```